# Python - how to return from n dimensional function a 1 dimensional function? - answered

Tags: python, function, optimization

I’m trying to create a function that receives n variables and returns the same function with one veritable.
my intention is to make a multi-dimentional search within a function in order to find its max point.

lets say i have a function: f(x1,x2,x3) = x1*x2+4*x3

my first phase of the algorithem will be to randomly choose a start point: x0 = (1,2,6)

now i have for every phase 3 iterations (one for each variable)

for the first one: f(x0+theta*(1,0,0)) = f1(theta) = (1+thata)*2+4*6

now in order to find the best direction i will apply golden slice on f1(theta) lets assume i recived theta = 2

my new x0 will be (1+2,2,6) and agein -> f(x0+thata*(0,1,0) -> golden slice-> optimum...

my question is how can i make a general function that recives multiple variables and returns function with one variable without knowing upfront which of the recived variables is with theta

Any ideas of how to realize it?

the soloution for the problem i presented is here:

```
def func(*args):
    x = []
    if args[0] == []:
        x.append(args[1])
        for i in args[2]:
            x.append(i)
    elif args[2] == []:
        for i in args[0]:
            x.append(i)
        x.append(args[1])
    elif args[2] == [] and args[0] == []:
        x.append(args[1])
    else:
        for i in args[0]:
            x.append(i)
        x.append(args[1])
        for i in args[2]:
            x.append(i)
    # write your target function
    h = (x[0] - 3) ** 2 + (x[1] - 2) ** 2 - x[0] * x[1] + x[2] + x[3]

    return h


def flatten(funci, *args, i,theta):
    lst1 = []
    lst2 = []
    for j in range(len(args[0])):
        if j < i:
            lst1.append(args[0][j])
        elif j > i:
            lst2.append(args[0][j])

    def inner(x):
        return funci(lst1, theta+x, lst2)

    return inner


p = [1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 6.0]
s = flatten(func, p, i=2,theta=4)
print(s(2.0))
```

Comment: Don't spell your keywords with capitals - it'll confuse others, future you and your IDE. Also, please fix your indentation - I'm pretty sure what you have there is not what you want. What is a "veritable"? What are `x1` and `x2`? What do you think `4x3` does? Your question looks an awful lot like an attempt at trolling here...

Comment: Where do the variables in `h = x1*x2+4x3` come from? I'm presuming this should be `h = x1 * x2 + (4 * x3)`. Please identify the source of the x variables: `x1`, `x2` and `x3`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for my spelling mistakes and for the unclear explanation...the variables come from f wich is a numpy arrey and ill fix the variable

Comment: Oh nice, you were able to adapt my flatten function to your needs :) Good luck for the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your intent rather than your very confused and confusing example. Here's what I wrote:

```
def flatten(func, *args):
    def inner(x):
        return func(x,*args[1:])
    return inner
```

Example 1

```
def f(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z

f2 = flatten(f,1,2,3)
print(f2(10))

# 15
```

Example 2

```
def g(sta, stb):
    return sta+" says hello "+stb

g2 = flatten(g,"Max","Tom")
print(g2("Wanda"))

# Wanda says hello Tom
```

Example 3 (with a mutable flattened argument)

```
def h(x, list):
    return [x+i for i in list]

l = [1,2,3]
h2 = flatten(h,1,l)

print(h2(10))
[11, 12, 13]

l[0]=11
print(h2(10))
[21, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Almost what i meant,  instead of numbers in x2 and x3 i need some expression of x1. I am looking for some general realization without knowing wich variables are expressed by other variable...hope i explained myself clearly) :

Comment: Oh, so what you need is not flattening a n-dimension function, but instead a simplification. But it's still not very clear; can you give examples of how x2 and x3 are written ? You say they come from your numpy array f: please give several examples of what f looks like.

Comment: For example: f(x1,x2,x3) = x1*x2 +4*x3 -> f(x1,2*x1, 5*x1) = x1*2*x1+4*5*x1 = f(x1)   meaning: the first function recieves list of diffrent expressions of x1 or other variable and returns another function of only 1 variable

Comment: Understood, but how are x2 and x3 defined in your f array?

Comment: Its like: f =(x1,x2,x3)

Comment: Where  and how (in which format) is it stated that x2 = (for example) 2*x1 ?

Comment: So my big intention is making a general algorithm for multidimentional searching in function: each iteration i take one direction first (1,0,0) second (0,1,0) and so on...basiclly we start from some random point (ex (2,-4,5)) then we add the direction multiply theta (ex (theta,0,0)) then the connection of those 2 vectors is what i send for my function wich will make it 1 dim function on the 1 dim function i am making the golden slice to recive the max arg of theta and return to the begining with the new point as my start point. In a few min ill edit my post hopefully it will be clearer